# How to combine bootstrap project with toggle side bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I've been experimenting to combine [this example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/) with [this toggle functionality](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/#menu-toggle) but I 'm failing miserably on CSS. Please point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5tamxgo2) it is.

Besides the standard porting code, I also added:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

to delay overlay you `body` tags. [Source](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top).

Comment: @George Oh, stop:) Glad to help you!